# Trying to split files using SystemCommandTasklet - Execution of system command did not finish within the timeout

Tags: spring-batch

I'm new to use Spring-batch and I'm trying to get an handle of the SystemCommandTasklet function. Files are not getting splitted from the code. split is working fine if executed as unix command

```
<!-- spring batch core settings -->
<import resource="../config/context.xml" />


<job id="accountingJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">

  <step id="step1" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">

     <tasklet ref="fileSplittingTasklet" />              

</step>  
</job>

<!-- Jobs to run -->

<bean id="fileSplittingTasklet" class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.SystemCommandTasklet" scope="step">
<property name="command" value="split -a 5 -l 4 #{jobParameters['inputFile']} #{jobParameters['stagingDirectory']}"/>
<property name="timeout" value="60000"/>
<property name="workingDirectory" value="/test/temp"/>
```

invoking code public class App {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    App obj = new App();
    obj.run();

}

private void run() {

    String[] springConfig = { "spring/batch/jobs/job-partitioner.xml" };

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);

    JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
    Job job = (Job) context.getBean("accountingJob");

    try {

        //JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("age", "20").toJobParameters();

        JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());

        System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());

        System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getAllFailureExceptions());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Done");

}
```

}`

getting time out error and no split is happening. Please find below error from console

```
INFO: Executing step: [step1]
```

Apr 19, 2017 7:07:33 AM org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep execute
SEVERE: Encountered an error executing the step
org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.SystemCommandException: Execution of system command did not finish within the timeout
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.SystemCommandTasklet.execute(SystemCommandTasklet.java:109)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:395)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:131)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:267)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:253)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:137)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:152)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:131)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:301)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:127)
        at com.mkyong.App.run(App.java:32)
        at com.mkyong.App.main(App.java:15)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)

Apr 19, 2017 7:07:33 AM org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1 run
INFO: Job: [FlowJob: [name=accountingJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [FAILED]
Job Parameters{}
Exit Status : FAILED
Job ParametersexitCode=FAILED;exitDescription=
Exit Status : [org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.SystemCommandException: Execution of system command did not finish within the timeout]
Done

Comment: Job parameters 'stagingDirectory' and 'inputFile' are undefined

Comment: Passing inputfile and stagingdirectory path as an argument while executing the jar. eg: java -jar split.jar inputfile=split.txt  stagingDirectoty /temp

Comment: Are you sure parameters are correctly forwarded from command line to tasklet? Place a brakepoint in SystemCommandTasklet and check what happens. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks a lot Luca Basso Ricci. Job Parameters are not set properly. I have corrected and it was working fine. Thanks for your help.